# array output being displayed on a single line instead of individual lines

Tags: ruby, docx

Im working with the `docx` gem, trying to get the output to match the format but I'm having some issues.

The output of the array items is always displayed on a single line like this `item 1 item 2 item 3`

I want the output to be displayed on a single line for each, like this

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

Heres my code

```
require 'docx'
require 'origami'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'date'
require 'libreconv'



todaysDate = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")
todaysDateSigned = Time.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

doc = Docx::Document.open('Change Request.docx')


puts '----------------------------'

puts 'Enter Client Name'
clientName = gets
clientName = clientName.strip

puts 'Enter Description'
description = gets
description = description.strip

puts 'Enter Hours'
hours = gets
hours = hours.strip

puts 'Enter Effects to other processes'
effects = gets
effects = effects.strip

puts 'process Name'
process = gets
process = process.strip


tasks = Array.new
puts 'Enter Needed Tasks'

loop do
  input = gets.chomp.capitalize
  break if input == ''
  tasks <<  input
end

tasks.join("\n")

tasks.each { |x|  doc.bookmarks['Tasks'].insert_text_after(x + "\n")}




doc.bookmarks['Description'].insert_text_after(description)
doc.bookmarks['Process'].insert_text_after(process)
doc.bookmarks['Date'].insert_text_after(todaysDateSigned)
doc.bookmarks['Date2'].insert_text_after(todaysDateSigned)
doc.bookmarks['Hours'].insert_text_after(hours)
doc.bookmarks['Effects'].insert_text_after(effects)
```

Comment: How much of what you've posted could you jettison and still have a self-contained program that runs and illustrates your problem?  What minor tweaks would you need to make to negate the need for us to guess what the external input ought to be?

Comment: I showed the desired result, the actual result and the path to get to the actual result in my code. What I didnt show were the 3 dozen other tests i ran before posting that yielded the same or worse results. This just seems like the way things go on the site, I post, someone doesnt like something about the way I post, downvotes it and then moves on without ever giving me feedback about it.

Comment: Yes, that's *exactly* how the site works. Votes are anonymous, and they aren't discussed. You vote, and then move on.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation shows that the method to use is `insert_multiple_lines_after` to create multiple lines from each entry in an array, however the correct method is called `insert_multiple_lines`

I changed this:

```
loop do
  input = gets.chomp.capitalize
  break if input == ''
  tasks <<  input
end

tasks.join("\n")

tasks.each { |x|  doc.bookmarks['Tasks'].insert_text_after(x + "\n")}
```

to this:

```
loop do
  input = gets.chomp.capitalize
  break if input == ''
  input = ' - ' + input
  tasks <<  input
end



doc.bookmarks['Tasks'].insert_multiple_lines(tasks)
```